# Asp MVC Core | Claims | Razor | Show/Hide elemts according to claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm server side guy and client side is nt mine))

So...I need in 2-3 days build pilot version as example for our team....and I have question

Lets say in system user has modules.

For example: 
1) Module E-Commerce
2) Module Messages

etc...

### In UI

*(update)*
**_Layout.cshtml**

Navigation panel
simple ui/li elements...
and I want if User has Claim Message - show (render) Message menu item
If not - not show (not render this item to HTML DOM.

Right now my code look as:

```
@{
                    var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

                    if(claimsIdentity != null)
                    {
                        var c = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("Modules");

                        if(c != null && c.Value == "MESSAGES")
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-puzzle-piece"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Messages</span></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="inbox.html"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>Inbox</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="Sent.html"><i class="fa fa-paragraph"></i>Sent emails</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This code work .....but ...

1) Because Im not write code everyday for UI, I dont know if this is best practies for manipulate with DOM??

2) For me its look very dirty........or this is normal for Asp MVC projects?

Maybe better write some statis convertor.....
Or maybe claims isnt best way to check modules?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a view model with a `bool ShowMessage` property and set the value in the controller before you pass the model to the view, so the view becomes just `@if(Model.ShowMessage) { .... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah, good idea..but!!)) this code in _Layout cshtml

Comment: Then you can have a base view model, and in the layout - @model MyBaseViewModel` (or you could just set a `ViewBag` property)

Comment: @MyBaseViewModel ......and do this static class....?
ViewBag ....From my knowledge...ViewBag pass from controlelr, right? So what is controller/action for _layout?

Comment: There is no controller action for a layout. You set the value in the method that calls the view (for example, using `ViewBag` you would use `ViewBag.ShowMessage = true;`, or if you have a `BaseViewModel` class with a `bool ShowMessage` property you initialize your inherited view model and set the value before passing the model to the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke hmmm...I will check (not really understand)...but will check ..
Thank you.
(I hope its not mena in ALL actions of ALL controllers I need pass ViewBag)??

Comment: You could use an `ActionFilter` to set it and then apply the filter globally (or just to specific controllers)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Hmmmm......Now you talk)) Yeah - ActionFilter is good idea....last question for you...if this way (claims, [@]if inside cshtml - is good and best practices?

Comment: In general, keep your view as simple as possible - i.e. `@if(someBoolProperty) { do something }` - the logic for setting `someBoolProperty` should be in the controller (also make it easier to unit test)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Ok, thnak you.
I just like clean code and Im felling not sure for C# inside web page. )